# cómo definir una función Python que reciba 2 strings y construya 2 nuevos strings que sean la mezcla de los 2 strings originales intercalando letras

Tags: python

Importante, sólo mezclar hasta la longitud de la palabra más corta.

El output de la función debe ser así:

```
texto_1='prueba' 

texto_2='textos'

In: mezclarPalabras(texto_1,texto_2) 

Out: ['peutbs', 'trxeoa']

texto_3='aaaaaaaaaa' 

texto_4='bbbb'

In: mezclarPalabras(texto_3,texto_4) 

Out: ['abab', 'baba']
```

Hasta el momento llevo esto:

```
def mezclarpalabras(string1, string2):
    x = string1
    y = string2
    z = ""
    if len(x) == len(y):
        return "".join(i for j in zip(string1,string2) for i in j)
```

De esta forma se puede generar un string con la mezcla de los dos originales intercalados. Pero no sé cómo crear 2 string con estas mezclas y que tengan la longitud de más corto.

Comment: Si quieres ayuda, tienes que publicar lo que has escrito hasta el momento.

Comment: Tu idea el join (fue idea tuya?) es correcta, y funciona también si las listas son de diferente longitud. Por tanto simplemente sobra la comparación del `len()`. También sobran por cierto las variables `x`,`y` y `z`

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería una función que hace lo que requieres, hay varias cosas que debes tener en cuenta. No obstante no es una duda lo que tienes, es mas bien problemas de algoritmia, pero igual aca te dejo un ejemplo para que te guíes sin usar funciones que todo lo hacen en python y puedas ver mas bien la solución y te sirva para entender un poco mejor. Algunas aclaraciones primero compruebas si las cadenas son distintas en longitud y buscas la menor, luego buscas la mayor y luego un ciclo para ir adicionando cada letra de cada cadena hasta la longitud de la menor.

```
def mezclarpalabras(cad1, cad2):
  if len(cad1) != len(cad2):
    min_cad=min(cad1, cad2, key=len)
    max_cad=max(cad1, cad2, key=len)
  else:
    min_cad=cad1
    max_cad=cad2

  result1=""
  result2=""
  for index in range(0, len(min_cad)):
    result1 += min_cad[index] + max_cad[index]
    result2 += max_cad[index] + min_cad[index]

  return (result1, result2)
```

Comment: Hola, la utilicé y funciona pero me da la longitud de ambas y no entiendo porqué :(

Comment: Hola, puedes explicar un poco mas? a que te refieres que te da la longitud de ambas? Deberías utilizar esa función asi: v1, v2 = mezclarpalabras("aaa", "bbb"), las variables v1 y v2 ahora almacenan el resultado de cada cadena